# Energy in general relativity - $p^t$ or $p_t$?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, conventions

I am slightly confused about what we call energy in general relativity. Minser, Thorne and Wheeler (pg657) use it as:
$$E=p^t$$
whilst this answer to one of my recent [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330409/) and other sources define it as
$$E=p_t$$
In most cases what we call 'energy' doesn't really matter. But for some it does, and in particular for the case of photons, in which according to Hobson, Efstathiou and Lasenby (pg12) has a four-momentum defined as:
$$p^\mu=(E/c,\vec p)$$
and hence this would suggest that $\nu\propto E\propto p^t$ but they then latter (pg222) say that:
$$E=p_\mu u^\mu$$
which indicates that $\nu\propto E\propto p_t$. My question is therefore, which of the equations in this question are correct, which are opinion based and which are wrong and why?

Answer (score 3):

If $\xi$ is a Killing vector of a certain metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, then the following quantity
$$
Q_\xi =  \xi^\mu p_\mu ~, \qquad p^\nu =  \frac{d x^\nu}{d\lambda}~, \quad p_\mu = g_{\mu\nu} p^\nu~.  
$$
is constant along all geodesics w.r.t. $g$. In particular, metrics that are globally hyperbolic have $\xi = - \partial_t$ has a Killing vector for some "time" coordinate $t$. The sign chosen here is a matter of convention. The conserved quantity corresponding to this Killing vector is what we call the energy. This is
$$
E = - p_t
$$
Thus, we note that the quantity that is conserved is $p_t$ ***not*** $p^t$. The former should be called the energy since it is the thing that is conserved.

Of course, when in Minkowski space, the difference between $p_t$ and $p^t$ is a sign so they are both conserved. In this case, it is irrelevant which quantity you define as energy. Here, it is simply a matter of convention.

Comment: OK thanks,  so $E=-p_t$ does that therefore mean for a photon $\nu \propto p_t$? and how would we go about defining its four-momentum?

Comment: Again, if you are working in Minkowski space you can just define it however you want since $E=-p_t=p^t$.

Comment: And if I am not working in Minkowski space (which I am not)?

Comment: Read my answer! I have clearly mentioned it there. On curved spacetimes, the conserved quantity is $-p_t$.

Comment: Sorry may be I am not making my self clear. I am asking, here, if this means that $\nu \propto p_t$ for photons and how we define its four momentum?

Comment: Four momentum on general spacetimes can only be defined if you have the corresponding symmetry, namely translational symmetry. I do not know what metric you have so I cannot say how one would define the four momentum on some random spacetime. The idea is the same as in the answer though. Given any Killing vector, you can define the conserved quantity as $\xi^\mu p_\mu$. Now, all you have to do is to determine what are the Killing vectors corresponding to the "four-momentum".

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification The components of the photon momentum $p_\mu$ are covariant, you can see it from the fact that the coordinate components are formally contravariant and the phase of the photon is something like $ \exp(i p_\mu x^\mu)$. I.e., yes, the frequency $\nu \sim p_t$.

Answer (score 0):

Energy and momentum organize themselves into a 4-vector $p_{\mu}$ in general relativity. Now, if you want to ask what a time-like observer measures as energy you need to first define the velocity vector of the observer as u^{\mu} such that $g_{\mu\nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}=1$. Then the energy the observer will measure at any point along their trajectory is $p_{\mu}u^{\mu}=p^{\mu}u_{\mu}$. In flat Minkowski space for an observer at rest $u^{\mu}={1,0,0,0}$, so they measured $E = p_{0}=-p^{0}$.